# KCL doesn't PUT or GET and items from DynamoDB checkpoint or locks tables

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl, spring-cloud-stream-binder, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis

I implemented reading messages from Kinesis using KCL, but when i check DynamoDB tables, i found that only group table have the list of shards, but checkpoint table and locks table doesn't have any items:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Any idea why KCL doesn't PUT or GET items from checkpoint and locks table?**

Answer (score 0):

There no relationship between Spring Integration `LockRegistry` + `MetadataStore` and KCL. The KCL solution just don't use Spring Integration. It relies on its own store based on the Checkpointer abstraction and CloudWatch.

The `LockRegistry` and `MetadataStore` are abstractions used by Spring Integration channel adapter implementation for plain AWS Kinesis client.

If you use KCL, then you don't need to use or worry about those extra tables for locks and metadata.